# Can I make a note in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Asking a question is not necessary when I want to create a note of something new.  Can I post a note?  If yes, then how?  I also wanted to know if there's anything tag-related to Astrology and Geography.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stack Overflow is a *question and answer* site, so asking and answering questions is pretty much always necessary by definition. :)

We do not yet have a site about geography or astrology.